How to concatenate a list of byte audio data (from frontend) into a single WAV file?
Body:
I am working with two types of audio data, both in byte form. One type works fine with audio processing libraries like pydub and AudioSegment, allowing me to concatenate and export the audio as a WAV file. However, the second type of audio data, which I receive from the frontend, cannot be processed by these libraries.
I can concatenate the byte data for transcription using b''.join(list), but when I try to save or play the concatenated audio, only the first segment plays. After it stops, I need to manually press the play button to hear the next segment.
Here’s the method that works for the first type of audio but not the second:
from pydub import AudioSegment
import io
import numpy as np

def audio_saver_AI(path, audio, dtype=np.int16):
    combined_audio = AudioSegment.empty()
    if isinstance(audio, list):
        for audio_file in audio:
            temp_audio = io.BytesIO(audio_file)
            audio_segment = AudioSegment.from_wav(temp_audio)  # Works with one type of audio
            combined_audio += audio_segment
    combined_audio.export(path, format='wav')

Problem:

This code works fine for the first type of audio I deal with, but for the audio data coming from the frontend, does not include RIFF header required to process it as a .wav  file, it can't be processed by AudioSegment or other similar libraries.
For transcription, b''.join(list) works fine for both audio types, but I cannot concatenate and play them back as a single continuous audio file.
I need a solution to properly concatenate the audio data received from the frontend and export it as a playable file.

What I've Tried:

Using AudioSegment and other libraries to concatenate the audio data, but they fail to process the frontend audio type.
Concatenating bytes for transcription with b''.join(list), which works but isn't sufficient for generating a playable audio file.

Question:
How can I concatenate a list of byte audio data (including the type received from the frontend) into a single audio file that can be saved and played back continuously?

what are the two types of audio?

There is no special type. One receiving from front-end, wav format that can't be processed, the 2nd type, generated by a TTS, that can easily be processed.

wav files have a header that includes the file length, so a simple concatenation will not work. You need to update the header with the new length and remove the header from the second file.

ffmpeg seems the right tool for this job

The audio file received from front end does not have RIFF  in header, that is required to process it as .wav files by the libraries designed to handle .wav files.

Do you know the data format (e.g. 16-bit PCM), sample rate and number of channels in the data sent by the frontend? You'll need that in order to successfully do, well, anything.

That's the problem, I have no idea. And I can't find it. All i can do right now is to save the audio in same chunks as coming from front end using python's default  with open('test.wav', 'wb') as f:.

Do you have any control over the frontend then? Can you look in the source to try and figure the format out?

It's a blob of audio with WAV format. const audioBlob = new Blob([audio], {type: "audio/wav"});

@Aleef That's... not really enough. What is audio? Why would the type be "audio/wav" if it doesn't have WAV headers?

@AKX :( . That's the problem here. The front end team is different and I am working on back end. The front end team is now working to debug the issue.

The frontend team should well know what the format is they're working with. There's really nothing to "debug" here, they'll just need to figure out how they're getting audio in the first place, and then they can tell you what the format is, and then you can interpret it as that format (e.g. sox (and ffmpeg) supports reading raw audio and adding the requisite WAV headers so you can work with regular tools).

If we write the audio to physical file before sending out in the front end. it works fine,
But when it is transferred to the python back end using python socket-IO, the RIFF header seems to be missing.
